# Why is MATLAB job taking a long time running?

Tags: multithreading, matlab, parallel-processing

I have a function (a convolution) which can get very slow if it operates on matrices of many many columns (function code below). I hence want to parallelize the code.

Example MATLAB code:

```
x = zeros(1,100);
x(rand(1,100)>0.8) = 1;
x = x(:);
c = convContinuous(1:100,x,@(t,p)p(1)*exp(-(t-p(2)).*(t-p(2))./(2*p(3).*p(3))),[1,0,3],false)
plot(1:100,x,1:100,c)
```

if `x` is a matrix of many columns, the code gets very slow... My first attempt was to change `for` to `parfor` statement, but it went wrong (see *Concluding remarks* below).

My second attempt was to follow [this example](http://www.mathworks.com/examples/parallel-computing/11612-trying-2-different-solvers-on-the-same-ode-system), which shows how to schedule tasks in a job and then submit the job to a local server. That example is implemented in my function below by letting the last argument `isParallel` being `true`.

The example MATLAB code would be:

```
x = zeros(1,100);
x(rand(1,100)>0.8) = 1;
x = x(:);
c = convContinuous(1:100,x,@(t,p)p(1)*exp(-(t-p(2)).*(t-p(2))./(2*p(3).*p(3))),[1,0,3],true)
```

Now, MATLAB tells me:

> Starting parallel pool (parpool) using the 'local' profile ... connected to 4 workers.
>
> Warning: This job will remain queued until the Parallel Pool is closed.

And MATLAB terminal keeps on hold, waiting for something to finish. I then open `Jobs Monitor` by `Home -> Parallel -> Monitor jobs` and see there are two jobs, one of which has the state `running`. But none of them will ever finish.

**Questions**

- Why is it taking too long to run, given it is a really simple task?
- What would be the best way to parallelize my function below? (the "heavy" part is in the separated function `convolveSeries`)

**File convContinuous.m**

```
function res = convContinuous(tData, sData, smoothFun, par, isParallel)
% performs the convolution of a series of delta with a smooth function of parameters par
% tData = temporal space
% sData = matrix of delta series (each column is a different series that will be convolved with smoothFunc)
% smoothFun = function used to convolve with each column of sData
%             must be of the form smoothFun(t, par)
% par = parameters to smoothing function
    if nargin < 5 || isempty(isParallel)
        isParallel = false;
    end
    if isvector(sData)
        [mm,nn] = size(sData);
        sData = sData(:);
    end
    res = zeros(size(sData));
    [ ~, n ] = size(sData);
    if ~isParallel
        %parfor i = 1:n % uncomment this and comment line below for strange error
        for i = 1:n
            res(:,i) = convolveSeries(tData, sData(:,i), smoothFun, par);
        end
    else
        myPool = gcp; % creates parallel pool if needed
        sched = parcluster; % creates scheduler
        job = createJob(sched);
        task = cell(1,n);
        for i = 1:n
            task{i} = createTask(job, @convolveSeries, 1, {tData, sData(:,i), smoothFun, par});
        end
        submit(job);
        wait(job);
        jobRes = fetchOutputs(job);
        for i = 1:n
            res(:,i) = jobRes{i,1}(:);
        end
        delete(job);
    end
    if isvector(sData)
        res = reshape(res, mm, nn);
    end
end

function r = convolveSeries(tData, s, smoothFun, par)
    r = zeros(size(s));
    tSpk = s == 1;
    j = 1;
    for t = tData
        for tt = tData(tSpk)
            if (tt > t)
                break;
            end
            r(j) = r(j) + smoothFun(t - tt, par);
        end
        j = j + 1;
    end
end
```

**Concluding remarks**

As a side note, I was not able to do it using `parfor` because `MATLAB R2015a` gave me a strange error:

> Error using matlabpool (line 27)
>   matlabpool has been removed.
>
> To query the size of an already started parallel pool, query the 'NumWorkers' property of the pool.
>
> To check if a pool is already started use 'isempty(gcp('nocreate'))'.
>
> Error in parallel_function (line 317)
>       Nworkers = matlabpool('size');
>
> Error in convContinuous (line 18)
>           parfor i = 1:n

My `version` command outputs

```
Parallel Computing Toolbox                            Version 6.6        (R2015a)
```

which is compatible with my MATLAB version. Almost [all other tests](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/92124-why-am-i-unable-to-use-matlabpool-or-parpool-with-the-local-scheduler-or-validate-my-local-configura) I have done are OK. I am then compelled to think that this is a MATLAB bug.

I tried changing `matlabpool` to `gcp` and then retrieving the number of workers by `parPoolObj.NumWorkers`, and after altering this detail in two different built-in functions, I received another error:

> Error in convContinuous>makeF%1/F% (line 1)
>
> function res = convContinuous(tData, sData, smoothFun, par)
>
> Output argument "res" (and maybe others) not assigned during call to "convContinuous>makeF%1/F%".
>
> Error in parallel_function>iParFun (line 383)
>     output.data = processInfo.fun(input.base, input.limit, input.data);
>
> Error in parProcess (line 167)
>         data = processFunc(processInfo, data);
>
> Error in parallel_function (line 358)
>     stateInfo = parProcess(@iParFun, @iConsume, @iSupply, ...
>
> Error in convContinuous (line 14)
>       parfor i = 1:numel(sData(1,:))

I suspect that this last error is generated because the function call inside `parfor` loop requires many arguments, but I don't really know it.

**Solving the errors**

Thanks to wary comments of people here (saying they could not reproduce my errors), I went on looking for the source of the error. I realized it was a local error due to having `pforfun` in my `pathdef.m` which [I downloaded long ago from File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26740-parallel-producer-consumer-for-matlabpool/content/pforfun/pforfun.m).

Once I removed `pforfun` from my `pathdef.m`, `parfor` (line 18 in `convContinuous` function) started working well.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Regarding your last error: Is this the full error stack? To which code does it belong, I am unable to find the lines in your code.

Comment: I've noticed the parallel pool holding jobs indefinitely as well when trying to run the batch examples from the documentation. It just goes somewhere, and when you do wait(job) it just is busy until you force kill matlab.

Comment: `convContinuous>makeF%1/F%` is the name of a function fabricated by the `parfor` machinery. It would be helpful to have executable reproduction steps to see what's going wrong. It's not immediately clear to me why you're seeing this - certainly your `convolveSeries` function unconditionally provides its output argument.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I was then able to find out that the last error was being generated by the function `parallel_function` which I though was a built-in function. But actually it is part of a code from File Exchange named `pforfun`. I removed `pforfun` from my `pathdef.m` and `parfor` worked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parallel pool you created is blocking your job from running. When you are using the jobs and tasks API you do not need (and must not have) a pool open. When you looked in Job Monitor, the running job you saw was the job that backs the parallel pool, that only finishes when the pool is deleted.

If you delete the line in `convContinuous` that says `myPool = gcp`, then it should work. As an optimization you can use the vectorised form of createTask, which is much more efficient than creating tasks in a loop i.e.

```
inputCell = cell(1, n);
for i = 1:n
    inputCell{i} = {tData, sData(:,i), smoothFun, par};
end
task = createTask(job, @convolveSeries, 1, inputCell);
```

However, having said all that, you should be able to make this code work using parfor. The first error you encountered was due to `matlabpool` being removed, it has now been replaced by `parpool`.

The second error appears to be caused by your function not returning the correct outputs, but the error message does not appear to correspond to the code you posted, so I'm not sure. Specifically I don't know what `convContinuous>makeF%1/F% (line 1)` refers to.

Comment: to reproduce the error, you would just need to uncomment line 18 of `convContinuous` function, where the `parfor` is stated and comment out the line below it with the `for` statement. However, as you people could not reproduce the problem, I went looking if I had a local problem instead of a MATLAB bug. The function `parallel_function` is a wrapper for `pforfun` which I long ago downloaded from File Exchange and had it in my `pathdef.m`. I removed it from `pathdef.m` and `parfor` started working normally.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to wary comments of people here (saying they could not reproduce my errors), I went on looking for the source of the error. I realized it was a local error due to having `pforfun` in my `pathdef.m` which [I downloaded long ago from File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26740-parallel-producer-consumer-for-matlabpool/content/pforfun/pforfun.m).

Once I removed `pforfun` from my `pathdef.m`, `parfor` (line 18 in `convContinuous` function) started working well.